# Add equality constraint and positive coefficients to quantile regression function in quantreg package in R

Tags: r, quantile-regression

I want to fit a quantile regression to
$y_t= \alpha+ \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 +\beta_3 x_3 + \beta_4 x_4 + \epsilon_t $ $\rightarrow$ (1)

rq function can do the job for me however I want to add two constraints at my coefficients

$\sum_{i=1}^4 \beta_i = 1 $

update::

I follow the below comment advise in order to impose the the first constraint $\sum_{i=1}^4 \beta_i = 1$  and I successfully solved my problem by rearrange my new model as :

$y_t-x_4 = \alpha+ \beta_1 ( x_1-x_4) + \beta_2 (x_2-x4) +\beta_3 (x_3-x4)  + \epsilon_t $ $\rightarrow$(2)
for simplicity we write :
$y^* = \alpha+ \beta_1 ( x_1^*) + \beta_2 (x_2^*) +\beta_3 (x_3^*)  + \epsilon_t$ $ \rightarrow$ (3) where $y^* := y_t-x_4  ... etc$

I added another constraint to my objective function which is $ \beta_i \geq 0 $
In order to impose a positive coefficients constraint my new model will be

$y^* =  \alpha+ e^ {\beta_1} ( x_1^*) + e^{\beta_2 } (x_2^*) +e^{\beta_3}(x_3^*)  + \epsilon_t$ $\rightarrow$ (4)

Then I fitted (4) by using nonlinear quantile regression function nlrq

```
mmm=nlrq(y.star~ exp(b1)*x1.star+exp(b2)*x2.star+exp(b3)*x3.star -1,start=list(b1=0,b2=0,b3=0) , tau=.05,trace=TRUE)

exp(coef(mmm))
```

please note I removed the intercept here.
I had the following results : $\beta_1 :0.55119833, \beta_2:  6.16095772, \beta_3: 0.01637757 $

my $\beta_4= 1 - \beta_1 - \beta_2 - \beta_3 =  -5.728534 $ which will satisfy my first constraint $\sum_{i=1}^4 \beta_i = 1 $ howwever it will violate my second constraint all coeff are positive.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Use your knowledge of algebra to express your model in the form $y_t-x_4=\alpha+\beta_1(x_1-x_4)+\beta_2(x_2-x_4)+\beta_3(x_3-x_4)+\epsilon_t$ and fit that. Finally, $\hat\beta_4=1-\hat\beta_1-\hat\beta_2-\hat\beta_3$ and you can compute its standard error in the usual way from the estimated variance matrix of the $\hat\beta_i.$  I'm pretty sure you can find detailed answers to this or very similar questions by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+fit+constraint).

Comment: Re the changed question: please search our site for posts about [monotonic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=monotonic+regression).

Comment: note that the function qr in your title refers to something completely different in R.